# Unable to load the driver. Error opening device /dev/scap0

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ubuntu-20.04, sysdig

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Kernel: 6.2.0-1018-azure
```

I followed the `sysdig` [setup guide for linux](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/How-to-Install-Sysdig-for-Linux) but am not able to figure out how to resolve this.

Post installation, if I run `sysdig` or `sudo sysdig`;

```
Unable to load the driver error opening device /dev/scap0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the scap module is loaded: No such file or directory
```

It looks like scap kernal module is not loaded, but where do I get it from and load it?
Also, I did not get this issue when installing on Ubuntu 16.04.

***Update (26 Dec, 2023):***

I am following the "Linux - Manual installation" method for installing sysdig:

```
curl -s https://download.sysdig.com/DRAIOS-GPG-KEY.public | sudo apt-key add -  
sudo curl -s -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/draios.list https://download.sysdig.com/stable/deb/draios.list  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get -y install sysdig
```

I have got this setup working on Azure VM which does not have secure boot enabled. I think, while installing with secure boot enabled, the scap.ko module is not installed during the `sudo apt-get install sysdig` and if I tried to install the `scap.ko` kernal module using `insmod` like;

> `sudo insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-1018-azure/updates/dkms/scap.ko`

I am getting the error `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module scap.ko: Key was rejected by service`

The goal is to setup sysdig as a daemonset on AKS!

Comment: "I followed the sysdig setup guide for linux" - How **exactly** have you setup sysdig on your machine? The guide suggests several ways. Please, add to your question post **exact steps** which have you performed.

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question and also added few things I tried.